# Is that possible for function to start late instead of delay?

Tags: jquery, delay

I have 2 jquery functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#title").click(function(){
            $("#click").delay(2700)
                    .css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"})
                        .animate({opacity: 0.5
                      });
                 });
             });
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").hover(
        function () {
          $("#card12").animate({top:'220px'},100);}, 
        function () {
          $("#card12").animate({top:'330px'},100);
         });
    });
```

This is how that's work:
   1. I click (div id = #title)
   2. (div id=#click) will shows up with 2700ms delay
   3. whenever I point my cursor to (div id=#click), (div id=#card12) will slides up

My problem is:
   1. I accidentally pointed my cursor into (div id =#click) area before 2700ms (the delay for (div id=#click) to shows up)
   2. Instead of ignoring it, the (div id=#card12) responded to that(sliding up) as soon as (div id=#click) has been completely loaded 


e.g: I point my cursor to (div id=#click) area, and move out the cursor outside the area back and forth for 2 times before 2700ms( the delay before (div id=#click) shows up).


Instead of ignoring that 2 initial hover ( before the (div id=#click shows up)), jQuery will slides (div id="#card12") twice, as soon as (div id=#click" has been completely loaded ( even though my cursor is outside the the(div id=#click) ) area by the time it has been loaded

My questions is:
 is that possible to ignore whatever happened before 2700ms (the #click delay before it shows up)?


P.S: I know it is easier if I can perform that using codePen/ jsFiddle. But I don't know how to use codePen/ jsFiddle using 2 jquery-(ies?)

Thank you very much

Comment: Just put both functions in the JS box in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmZjK/. Not difficult ;)

Comment: Please add your relevant HTML which you are referring to in your script. That way we might be able to do our own jsfiddle to play around with enabling us to better understand your issue and come up with a solution. Or dump all your scripts as they are in the jsFiddle yourself and add the relevant HTML yourself and post the fiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your hover jQuery in the callback of your first animate jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#title").click(function () {
    $("#click").delay(2700).css({opacity: 0.0,visibility: "visible"}).animate({
      opacity: 0.5}, function () {
      $("#click").hover(function () {
        $("#card12").animate({top: '220px'}, 100);
      },function () {
        $("#card12").animate({top: '330px'}, 100);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider adding the hover binding within the click function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#title").click(function(){
        $("#click").delay(2700)
            .css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"})
            .animate({opacity: 0.5})
            .hover(
                function () {
                    $("#card12").animate({top:'220px'},100);}, 
                function () {
                    $("#card12").animate({top:'330px'},100);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your #click element shows up after the delay, and only then you want the user to be able to click on it and show the card element. One simple fix is to use display:none vs. visibility:hidden. This may or may not be an option. The upside to visibility is that your element maintains its space, but there are ways around that. If using display: none is not an option, I think what you want to achieve could be done by doing the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#title").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#click").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity:0.5});
            $("#click").hover(
                function () {
                    $("#card12").animate({top:'220px'},100);}, 
                function () {
                    $("#card12").animate({top:'330px'},100);
                }
            );
        },2700);
    });
});
```

I cannot see your code, but assuming your #click element is a child of your #title element, I would use the above code, but change #click to $(this).children() type selector so as to get the correct element. However, since it appears you are using ids as selectors rather than classes, I assume there is only one of each element on the page, and using ids as selector should be fine.
Basically my code assigns the hover event listener after 2700 miliseconds, which is what the setTimeout is for.